# Serializing different fields from the same object on Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm new on Retrofit and I have some doubts about how to use it in Android. I have a model with four fields (id, password, firstName and lastName), and I want to do two different POST calls from the same object but with different fields. On the one hand, I want to create a login call with the id and password. And, on the other hand, I want to create another call with the firstName and lastName. I'm using the @Expose annotation with the serialized=true, but then the 4 fields are being always sent. Is there a way to send different fields depending on the call? I've seen that I could use a type adapter but I don't know how I does it work. 
I'm using the version 2.0.0 from Retrofit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you'll try to implement your requirements, you'll find retrofit meets most of your requirements. Check for examples available online. Try https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/samples . Please modify and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I've created a custom class that implements JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer, so I pass an array with the fields that must be serialized/deserialized. The last thing I had to do was registering the type adapter (registerTypeAdapter) on the gson builder object.

This is working perfect!